# add Database to ASP.net core

Tags: database, asp.net-core, database-connection

Hey i know this is probably simple question but i'm not too familiar with a lot of these things. I'm creating a ASP.Net core project but i'm not sure how to add my database to it . i'm using VS 15.6.4 and when i click on tools >>connect to database  i get a couple of options but I'm not sure which one to pick or how to make the connection. I already have the database created thats why im doing it like that im also using EF. any guidance would be helpful. please keep the explanations elementary as i'm still a beginner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the detailed information here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-aspnet-core